# Filter datasource where column like/contains VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, filter

---

UPDATE

Thanks to Hanlet the problem is solved, the syntax is like so:

```
source1.Filter =  "[Column] LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

Also for anyone interested, this is the syntax for performing the above on multiple criteria:

```
source1.Filter = "[Column1] LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%' OR [Column2] LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"
```

---

I currently have code to filter my datasource where the column 'Customer Name' equals the text in the text box.

However, what I want is a filter that is similar to the LIKE function in sql, so if the customer name is 'John' and the user inputs 'Jo' into the text box, it will filter all customers who's name is LIKE/contains 'Jo'

This is the current filter code (if you want the code showing how the data is bound just ask):

```
 Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
 source1.Filter = "[Customer Name] = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"
 dTableMain.Refresh()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `BindingSource`'s filter should work with the Like comparison. Try it: `[Customer Name] LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'"`

Comment: Ah thanks that worked! I thought there must have been a way to do it , but wasn't sure of the syntax. Thanks again! +1

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past. Here's the general syntax:

```
' The searchString is searched for in both the Cost Center field AND the Code field
BindingSource.Filter = "[col1] like " & searchString & " OR [col2] like " & searchString
```

In your case, it would be:

```
source1.Filter = "[Customer Name] like " & TextBox1.Text
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, this helped me! Hanlet gave me the correct syntax in his comment. Thanks again! +1

Comment: @CallumHolden: we must have been posting at the same time, he just beat me to it! No worries though, glad it helped :)